# OpenCV's cv::Mat & CvMat row alignment

Tags: opencv, memory-alignment

could someone pls explain to me how the row alignment of OpenCV's `CvMat` (or its C++ version `cv::Mat`) works? For instance, let's assume I have a matrix

```
CvMat *cvmat = cvCreateMat(2,3,CV_8UC1);
cvSet2D( cvmat, 0, 0, cvScalar(1) );
cvSet2D( cvmat, 0, 1, cvScalar(2) );
cvSet2D( cvmat, 0, 2, cvScalar(3) );
cvSet2D( cvmat, 1, 0, cvScalar(4) );
cvSet2D( cvmat, 1, 1, cvScalar(5) );
cvSet2D( cvmat, 1, 2, cvScalar(6) );
```

According to the documentation of `CvMat`, rows should be aligned by 4 bytes, i.e. first row of the matrix should be padded by one zero and the second should start at the offset +4). However, if I debug this piece of code, the data are continuous (i.e. `cvmat->data` is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`) and I don't see any 4-byte alignment. Is this a bug in documentation and is it always safe to assume the continuity of the data of `CvMat` or `cv::Mat` (in the case that the matrix is not part of another ofc)? Or are there some special configurations in which there could be some gaps in the data as a result of memory alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not safe to assume the continuity. `cv::Mat` has a member function `isContinuous` that you can check for continuity (the C API has a macro for that, as the comment says):

```
// returns true iff the matrix data is continuous
// (i.e. when there are no gaps between successive rows).
// similar to CV_IS_MAT_CONT(cvmat->type)
bool isContinuous() const;
```

There's also a member `step` that tells you the offset between consecutive rows:

```
// a distance between successive rows in bytes; includes the gap if any
size_t step;
```

So, assuming you have an 8-bit single channel image, the pixel at (x, y) is at offset `y * step + x`.

There's a number of situations where you end up with non-continuous memory, and they are not restricted to memory alignment. E.g., if you say `cv::Mat r = mat.col(0)`, the data is not copied, but `r` points to the same memory region as `mat`, just with a different "header", so the "gap" that you have there is the data from the matrix that is not in column 0.

Comment: Maybe I asked the question in a wrong way. I know about the members of `cv::Mat` and special cases where matrix can be part of another. But what I don't understand is 4 byte row alignment. Because of that, for example, I've been writing all foreach(y,x) nested for loops with the pointer to the y-th row being reinitialized on every y-th iteration, which can result in cumbersome code and unnecessary computations...

Comment: With the C++ interface, the code isn't really cumbersome. The answer still stands - "It's not safe to assume continuity". If the implementation does happen to use continuous memory (iirc it doesn't in the case of multichannel matrices for example), that might change without notice.

Comment: I think `step` is only defined for CvMat, and for cv::Mat you should use instead the method [`step1()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-step1)