# 2D Image Indexing Bug in CUDA Kernel

Tags: cuda

I'm doing linear filtering on images using CUDA. I use 2D thread blocks and 2D grid to make the problem natural. Here's how I index: (**height** and **width** are image dimensions)

```
dim3 BlockDim(16,16);

dim3 GridDim;
GridDim.x = (width + 15) / 16;
GridDim.y = (height + 15) / 16;
```

In kernel I access the locations as follows:

```
unsigned int xIndex = blockIdx.x*16+ threadIdx.x;
unsigned int yIndex = blockIdx.y*16+ threadIdx.y;
unsigned int tid = yIndex * width + xIndex;
```

And I want to return four boundaries (i'll cater them later on). I do this as:

```
if(yIndex>=height-N || xIndex>=width-N || yIndex<N || xIndex<N)
  return;
```

Where N is the number of pixels at each boundary I don't want to calculate.

**Problem:**

The code runs fine on all standard images sizes. But for some random image sizes it shows diagonal line(s). For example in my case 500x333 image (even when no dimension is multiple of 16) is showing correct output whereas 450x365 is showing diagonal lines in the output. The problem remains even if I just return the extra threads of grid and nothing else like this:

```
if(yIndex>=height || xIndex>=width)
return;
```

The code remains the same, some inputs run fine while others don't. Can anybody spot the bug? I have attached the input and output samples here: [IMAGES](http://www.hardwareinsight.com/IMAGES.zip) Thanks!

**Update:**

Kernel Code (Simplified to return input image, but gives the same problem)

```
__global__ void filter_8u_c1_kernel(unsigned char* in, unsigned char* out, int width, int height, float* filter, int fSize)
{
    unsigned int xIndex = blockIdx.x*BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int yIndex = blockIdx.y*BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int tid = yIndex * width + xIndex;

    unsigned int N = filterSize/2;

    if(yIndex>=height-N || xIndex>=width-N || yIndex<N || xIndex<N)
        return;

       /*Filter code removed, still gives the same problem*/

    out[tid] = in[tid];
}
```

**Update 2:**

I have also removed the **return** statement by reversing the **if** condition. But the problem persists.

```
if(yIndex<=height-N && xIndex<=width-N && yIndex>N && xIndex>N){

  /*Kernel Code*/

}
```

Comment: Without seeing code it will be very hard to answer, but I would be very suspicious of *ever* using return statements inside kernels. If you have memory or instruction synchronization barriers in the code, then it could well be the return statements themselves which are causing the problem.

Comment: I have added the code in update. It's Pretty much the same that I put earlier.

Comment: Can you add the kernel arguments and launch parameters you are using to a case which fails? Also `filterSize` is undefined at the moment, should it be `fSize`?

Comment: I already mentioned the launch parameters in the question. filterSize can be any, like 3,5,7,9 .. It's helps calculate N which sets the offset pixels at boundaries. Practically if I hardcode N to any value, it doesn't make a difference. At this configuration where I copy just input image to output all standard size work, and some others too but at few images size e.g.450x364 it gives wrong output. Kindly see the attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few things you still haven't described very well, but based on the information you have posted, I built what I am guessing is a reasonable repro case with parameters which match a case you say it failing (450 x 364 with `filterSize=5`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

template<int filterSize>
__global__ void filter_8u_c1_kernel(unsigned char* in, unsigned char* out, int width, int height, float* filter, int fSize)
{
    unsigned int xIndex = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int yIndex = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int tid = yIndex * width + xIndex;

    unsigned int N = filterSize/2;

    if(yIndex>=height-N || xIndex>=width-N || yIndex<N || xIndex<N)
        return;

    out[tid] = in[tid];
}

int main(void)
{
    const int width = 450, height = 365, filterSize=5;
    const size_t isize = sizeof(unsigned char) * size_t(width * height);
    unsigned char * _in, * _out, * out;

    assert( cudaMalloc((void **)&_in, isize) == cudaSuccess ); 
    assert( cudaMalloc((void **)&_out, isize) == cudaSuccess ); 
    assert( cudaMemset(_in, 'Z', isize) == cudaSuccess );
    assert( cudaMemset(_out, 'A', isize) == cudaSuccess );

    const dim3 BlockDim(16,16);
    dim3 GridDim;
    GridDim.x = (width + BlockDim.x - 1) / BlockDim.x;
    GridDim.y = (height + BlockDim.y - 1) / BlockDim.y;

    filter_8u_c1_kernel<filterSize><<<GridDim,BlockDim>>>(_in,_out,width,height,0,0);
    assert( cudaPeekAtLastError() == cudaSuccess );

    out = (unsigned char *)malloc(isize);
    assert( cudaMemcpy(out, _out, isize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) == cudaSuccess);

    for(int i=0; i<width; i++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d: ", i);
        for(int j=0; j<height; j++) {
            unsigned int idx = i + j*width;
            fprintf(stdout, "%c", out[idx]);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    }

    return cudaThreadExit();
}
```

When run it does exactly what I would expect, overwriting the output memory with the input everywhere except for the first and last two lines and the first and last two entries in all the lines in between. This is running with CUDA 3.2 on OS X 10.6.5 with a compute 1.2 GPU. So whatever is happening in you code, it isn't happening in my repro case, which either means I have misinterpreted what you have written, or there is something else you haven't described which is causing the problem.

Comment: I tested your code on my machine and it works perfect, gives the correct output. So this made me pluck out my code from the whole framework and make a project specifically for this kernel. I am reading images using OpenCV (available freely). Same kernel is giving incorrect output on 450x364 when fed with an image read via OpenCV. Standard image sizes works fine, Do you think it might be OpenCV problem? I'm attaching the complete project here, please take a look: http://hardwareinsight.com/so.zip

Comment: @JawadMasood: OpenCV images are not always continuous, i.e. all bytes lie consecutive in memory. There can be gaps between image rows. How do you access the image data? If `bool Mat::isContinuous()` returns `false`, you should access it taking `size_t Mat::step` into account. See [OpenCV Mat documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002674).

Comment: @JawadMasood: Sorry, but no. You asked a question about kernel indexing schemes, and it has, I believe, been satisfactorily answered. I am not delving into a sprawling OpenCV project to try and find your bugs. If you can isolate a question related to OpenCV, then I suggest you post a new, OpenCV focussed question.

Comment: Actually I found the problem. The imageStep is not always equal to the width*numberOfChannel. In this case the image of 450x364 had the step size of 452!!! OpenCV also reads the step size. All I had to do was change width to step in the caller function. You've been a lot of help in figuring out this problem. I'm accepting your answer as correct one! Thanks :)